# Finding OS files corresponding to Java imports. For example, finding source files where only an inner class is imported from another file

Tags: java, import, classloader

I need to find the OS files in the class path corresponding to imports in Java files.

I have code which parses java files, obtains their imports and then locates the source files in the class path which correspond to the given import.  If no java file is found, it then finds .class files or resources in jars.  To accomplish this I use the call below.

```
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(import)
```

To do this successfully I have had to replace **"."** with **"/"** in the import and append the appropriate extension.  For example, to look for java files, I need to append a ***".java"*** to the import string above.

So "*a.b.c*" would become "*a/b/c.java*" and "*a/b/c.class*" respectively.

Now this works fine and gives me the results I want.The problem comes in when locating nested classes and static imports.For eg. If we have a `class A (in package p)` which `contains an inner class B`, and we have an import "`import p.A.B;`", and we have the source code for A in the classpath as `A.java`  I can't easily find out that `the file corresponding to B is actually A.java`.  Is there any way to do this without guessing?

Comment: For classes, call .getEnclosingClass() until you get null (to un-nest).  For static imports, the named entity will be a field, method, or nested class (or *).  Chop off the last token and use the .getEnclosingClass() un-nester to find the file.  I'll add that it's possible to jam multiple classes into one java source file (but only one of them may be public).

Answer (score 0):

I might not understood your question properly, but the compiler will create a .class file called A$1B.class for an inner class called B (encolsing class A), so the first part of the filename is your enclosing class, and that will tell you in which .java file the code resides in (i.e. A.java).

Example:
I have a class called Test and I create an inner class called InnerClass. I compile and get

```
Test.class
Test$InnerClass.class
```

So, the first part of the filename, prior to the $ is your enclosing class name, in this case Test. When you know this you can look for .java file called Test.java.

Hth

Comment: Yeah i know, but the issue is that i am going from an import to a .java file. So i don't know the name of the file.  Ie. import package.classA.classB;  I can't look for classB.java as classB is an inner class of A, hence i have to guess and try different variations. Not elegant.  Also this won't work for static imports eg. import package.ClassA.CONSTANT, as CONSTANT is not a class i can't do anything with it except look it up, if it's not found try the parent of the import ie. package.ClassA.  none of these are elegant solutions.

Comment: If by elegant you mean easy then I don't think there's any viable option. Maybe consider using javap.exe tool?

Comment: ah ok.  I was hoping lol.  So the best option i found so far is to get the import decleartion, replace . with slash and append .java extension.  If it does not exist then remove the last name from the import and try again.  Eg. if a.b.c.java is not found then try a.b.java and so on.  Can you think of a more elegant/better option than this or is this basically the easiest?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the compiled class files? Class files include the name of the source file from which they were compiled, which is what you need to know. You can see this by running javap on one - the first line says "Compiled from", and gives the filename. eg:

```
$ javap java.lang.Character.UnicodeBlock
Compiled from "Character.java"
public final class java.lang.Character$UnicodeBlock extends java.lang.Character$Subset{
```

You only get the filename, not the full path, but you can do a bit of string manipulation to construct it. The cases you need to think about are:

1. The filename matches the last part of the fully-qualified name: this is a normal top-level class
2. The filename matches an earlier part of the fully-qualified name: this is an inner class
3. The filename does not match any part of the fully-qualified name: this is a non-public top-level class declared in the same source file as another class; this is very unusual, and possibly not worth dealing with if you know you don't have any classes like this

Comment: I did not know you could do that. That's interesting information but unfortunately i'm writing this program to compile the program using the minimum set of dependent files and package it in a jar so i don't have access to the compiled files.  I'm the one trying to compile them.

Answer (score 0):

No.

There's nothing in the source-level name of a class that lets you figure out if it's an inner class or not. It sounds from your description like you're limited to precisely that information.